# Can't seem to obtain this diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I'm trying to diagonalise the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix}3&-1&1\\0&2&2\\1&-1&3 \end{pmatrix}$. I know that the answer is $D = \begin{pmatrix}2&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&4 \end{pmatrix}$ but I'm trying to understand the full process of getting there.

I found a basis for A consisting of eigenvectors which is $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} -1\\ 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$.

So using $P^{-1}AP=D$, we have $P = \begin{pmatrix}1&-1&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $P^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\-1/2&1/2&1/2\\1/2&-1/2&1/2 \end{pmatrix}$.

Then $D=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\-1/2&1/2&1/2\\1/2&-1/2&1/2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}3&-1&1\\0&2&2\\1&-1&3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&1 \end{pmatrix}$

$\implies D=\begin{pmatrix}4&0&0\\1&2&0\\1&0&2 \end{pmatrix}$ which clearly isn't what I want. Where did I mess up?

Comment: Are you sure that your second and third eigenvectors are eigenvectors?

Comment: Textbook and I both obtained the same answer so I think so? But not impossible that it's wrong I guess

Comment: I would double check whether or not $Av$ is a scalar multiple of $v$ for $v=(-1,0,1)^T$ and $v=(1,0,1)^T$

Comment: Matlab gives 1 pair of complex eigenvalues for your $A$.

Comment: The eigenvectors are $(1,1,0)^T \ (1,1-i,1)^T \ (1,1+i,1)^T$. There is your mistake.

Comment: Your matris is *not* diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the insight everyone

Comment: If you work backwards from the supposedly correct $D$ and the eigenbasis that you found, you get a matrix that’s almost $A$, except that its $2,3$ element is zero. Perhaps there’s a typo in the textbook or you misread the problem.

Comment: Looks like there was a typo in the textbook and the actual matrix was supposed to be $A = \begin{pmatrix}3&-1&1\\0&2&0\\1&-1&3 \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $v_1:=\begin{pmatrix} -1\\ 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v_2:=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ are not eigenvectors of $A$ because $$Av_1=-2v_1+\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 2\\ 0\end{pmatrix}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad Av_2=4v_1+\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 2\\ 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
In fact the matrix is not diagonalizable over $\Bbb{R}$ because its characteristic polynomial
$$P_A(X)=X^3-8X^2+22X-20=(X-2)(X^2-6X+10),$$
has nonreal roots, because $X^2-6X+10$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{R}$.